# eliminating a whole group which doesn't meet minimum date - SQL Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, subquery, min, date-arithmetic

I have a table with order ID, Country, order date, product name and quantity. As you can see one unique order ID is composed of a few products/records but spread around different dates. I need my query to retrieve only records of an order that all of its records order date is later than 6/11/2022; so for example: I need the query to completely eliminate all of order 222 as at least one of its records is earlier than 6/11/2022, and the same goes for order 111 (at least one of its records is earlier than 6/11/2022). As you can see, only order 333 meets that criteria. I'm trying to group by order ID and country, and then eliminating the whole order records according to the criteria, the issue is it will just eliminate a specific record which is earlier than 6/11/2022 - but not the whole order records:
code:

```
select order ID, order date, product, quantity from Orders table
group by order ID, country
HAVING MIN(order date) > '6/11/2022'
```

Orders table:

| order Id | country | order date | product | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | UK | 05/11/2022 | keyboard | 2 |
| 222 | UK | 05/11/2022 | motherboard | 2 |
| 222 | UK | 07/11/2022 | wireless mouse | 1 |
| 111 | Germany | 08/11/2022 | game console | 5 |
| 111 | Germany | 05/10/2022 | mini keyboard | 3 |
| 111 | Germany | 08/10/2022 | 5 mini discs bundle | 1 |
| 111 | Germany | 10/10/2022 | backup disc | 5 |
| 333 | France | 09/12/2022 | backup disc | 2 |
| 333 | France | 10/12/2022 | backup disc | 1 |

Query desired result:

| order Id | country | order date | product | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 333 | France | 09/12/2022 | backup disc | 2 |
| 333 | France | 10/12/2022 | backup disc | 1 |

the results I'm getting - not the desired results:

| order Id | country | order date | product | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | UK | 07/11/2022 | wireless mouse | 1 |
| 111 | Germany | 08/11/2022 | game console | 5 |
| 333 | France | 09/12/2022 | backup disc | 2 |
| 333 | France | 10/12/2022 | backup disc | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to compute the earliest date per order/country tuple *on each row*, then use that information to filter the dataset:

```
select *
from (
    select o.*,
        min(date) over(partition by order_id, country) min_date
    from orders o
) o
where min_date > date '2022-11-06'
```

This scans the table only once, hence it should be more efficient than the `group by`/`join` solution.